# I created a laravel and then

Tags: database, laravel, pivot, many-to-many, pivot-table

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base
> table or view not found: 1146 Table
> 'db_testmasjid.jamaah_model_kajian_model' doesn't exist (SQL: select
> `kajian`.*, `jamaah_model_kajian_model`.`jamaah_model_id` as
> `pivot_jamaah_model_id`, `jamaah_model_kajian_model`.`kajian_model_id`
> as `pivot_kajian_model_id` from `kajian` inner join
> `jamaah_model_kajian_model` on `kajian`.`id` =
> `jamaah_model_kajian_model`.`kajian_model_id` where
> `jamaah_model_kajian_model`.`jamaah_model_id` = 4)'

Comment: can u show the query you are running

Comment: Did you run migrations `php artisan migrate`? If so, do you have a migration for `db_testmasjid.jamaah_model_kajian_model`?

Answer (score 0):

first you have to run `php artisan migrate` to create  tables in your database and then your query will work perfectly